# iPhone app which syncs Outlook memos while maintaining categories

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, notes.app

I am looking for an iPhone app which will synchronise with Microsoft Outlook memos, while maintaining the categories which I have set up in Outlook.  From my understanding, the Notes application which comes bundled in with the iPhone doesn't have any categories.

Any recommendations about an app which will do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [iMExchange 2](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imexchange-2/id390716055) ($8 after trial period) might do the trick for you if you or your company are running an Exchange Server.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I just installed the trial version.  If I change a memo in Outlook, it correctly syncs to the iPhone.  However, if I change a memo on the iPhone, it seems to revert the change immediately (IOW, the memos on the iPhone seem to be read-only).  Is this expected behaviour, or it this just an issue in the trial version?

Comment: The trial should be fully functional, and I'm pretty sure that's not the expected behavior.  If you think it might be a problem with your setup, try posting a specific question about it here on Ask Different.  If you think it might be a bug in the app, you could try contacting the developer: http://rerlsoft.com/home/FAQ_And_Contact_Details.html